# Getting a notification if an application is trying to send an sms programmatically on a non rooted android device

Tags: android, security, sms

Subject of discussion: User security on non rooted Android phones.

Is it possible to notify the user if an application is trying to send an sms programmatically?

I am trying to do some research on Android malwares that send sms on premium numbers without letting the users know. These apps hide as trojans.

A lot of questions have been asked about how to send sms programmatically, which in itself is not that difficult but my question is:

If some other application tries to do the same, is it possible to write some form of a broadcast intent to catch such actions and ask users if this is legit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we could do is use a very high priority broadcast intent receiver for SMS sent and let user know via a toast or any notification if the numbers are not in the phonebook. Yes, a user can herself send sms to numbers but then the suggested solution could be one extra step of safety for her!